# NSMutableArray adds object locally, but seems to clear when accessed in the next function

Tags: ios, properties, nsmutablearray, return-value, setting

So basically, I declare an NSMutableArray, alloc and init it in the viewdidload, call a function that adds an object to the array (which I verify with an NSLog right after its added), but then when the next method is called and tries to access the NSMutableArray— it goes blank.

What is going on here?

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray * array;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize array;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{          
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self firstfunction];
    if (j.intValue == 1)
    {
        [self secondfunction];
    }

}

- (void)firstfunction
{
    //a bunch of stuff happens with a server
    [array addObject:object];   

    NSLog(@"There are %d in array",array.count);
    //** NSLOG RETURNS "THERE ARE 1 IN ARRAY" **//

    [tableView reloadData];

    //clean up code
    j = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
}

- (void)secondfunction
{
    NSLog(@"There are these many in the array now %d",array.count);
    //**NSLOG RETURNS:"There are these many in the array now 0"**//
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can not say what's wrong until see the code where you have used your array or where you have set your array

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I am using ARC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write [self secondfunction]; at the end of first function.
Reason is, before the array is filled your second function is called.

Comment: I have a checker that returns an int==1 when the first function ends and an if statement that checks if the int ==1. It still has a problem. Thanks though!

Comment: Ok try one condition: if([array count] > 0){//call your second function}else{//NO}

Comment: I can try that, but the problem is that sometimes array can == 0.

Comment: As per my understanding the problem is just with the completion of blocks and function calls. If you try to call second function only after filling array, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: I tried calling the function with the if statement parameter since I happened to know that there was something in the array this time and it actually calls the function but the value inside the function is still 0. Also I deleted that and called [self secondfunction]; at the end of the firstfunction and it still passes 0 array items to the other function despite returning 1 object in the NSLog of the first function. :\

Comment: Have you tried to put hardcoded values in array and then call second function?

Comment: For some reason I had to call [self secondfunction]; in the loop of the adding objects sequence of the first function. So I just wait until i (my variable incrementing in the loop) hits the total count of the objects being added to the array before calling the function. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

because I think you are having the server link code in some asynchronous block.SO after you got the results you are adding it to the array,But secondFunction is executed before you get the results and add it to array.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)firstfunction{
   //a bunch of stuff happens with a server
   [array addObject:object];
   NSLog(@"There are %d in array",array.count);
   [tableView reloadData];
   [self secondfunction];
}

-(void)secondfunction{
   NSLog(@"There are these many in the array now %d",array.count)
   //**NSLOG RETURNS:"There are these many in the array now 0"**//
}
```